# Django: form not displaying in browser

Tags: django, forms

The form doesn't display in the browser.  The navbar and submit button show up but no form in between.  The problem must be straightforward but I haven't been able to find the issue.  Thank you for your help.

views.py

```
def ProductCreateView(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('set_app/product_list.html'))
else:
    product_form = ProductForm()
return render(request, 'set_app/product_form.html', {'product_form':product_form})
```

forms.py

```
class ProductForm(forms.Form):
class Meta():
    model = models.Product
    fields = ('code', 'barcode', 'name', 'description', 'brand', 'status')
```

product_form.html

```html
{% extends "set_app/basic_app_base.html" %}
{% block body_block %}
    <h1>
        {% if not form.instance.pk %}
            Create Product
        {% else %}
            Update Product
        {% endif %}
    </h1>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ product_form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue:

in forms.py
instead of

```
class ProductForm(forms.Form):
```

it should be

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
```